# Mirror of a binary tree using STL queue

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I was trying to get mirror image of a binary tree,but due to having less knowledge about pointers i had hard time in debugging my code.Can you guys plzz help me to debug the code...

> Algorithm:

1. Traverse the tree using level order travesal(right to left)
2. Then on popping out the front node create the mirror tree

   [image: []]

   [See my code here.](http://dpaste.com/2ER55DZ)

What i am doing?

1. Inserting root into queue and then run the while(!queue.empty()).
2. Pop out the front element and insert it into mirror tree
3. Then, push front->right then front->left.

I know its a very trivial question and but just for my clear understanding about pointers i am posting it here.Also i am unable to understand what my compiler is saying.Hers's a snapshot while i try to compile.
[image]
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks!!!

Comment: When people post code without errors, at least we can compile it ourselves. What do you expect us to do with a picture of an error log an no code?

Comment: Your implementation is having a lot of technical error. Please have a look into this article http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-an-efficient-c-function-to-convert-a-tree-into-its-mirror-tree/

Comment: The code is in the link @StoryTeller

Comment: I think it is a lot easier if you pose the solution in a recursive way.  Review my answer for more details

Comment: Yes, it is, but I was looking for an iterative version.Thanks for the suggestion !!! @lrleon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected the code. Please see if this helps

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct treenode{
  int data;
  struct treenode* left , *right;
};


struct treenode* createNode(int data)
{
  struct treenode* node = (struct treenode*)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));
  node->data = data;
  node->right = NULL;
  node->left = NULL;
  return node;
}


//Function for inserting node for creating mirror of binary tree
void insert(struct treenode **root2,int data)
{
  struct treenode* temp;
  if(*root2 == NULL)
  {
    *root2 = createNode(data);
    return;
  }
  else{
    queue<treenode*> q;
    q.push(*root2);
    while(!q.empty())
    {
      temp = q.front();
      q.pop();
      if(temp->left)
      q.push(temp->left);
      else{
        temp->left = createNode(data);
        return;
      }
      if(temp->right)
      {
        q.push(temp->right);
      }
      else{
        temp -> right = createNode(data);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}

void mirror(struct treenode* node) 
{
  if (node==NULL) 
    return;  
  else
  {
    struct treenode* temp;

    /* do the subtrees */
    mirror(node->left);
    mirror(node->right);

    /* swap the pointers in this node */
    temp        = node->left;
    node->left  = node->right;
    node->right = temp;
  }
} 

//For printing the tree
void level_order(struct treenode** root)
{
  if(root==NULL) return;
  queue<treenode*> q;
  q.push(*root);
  while(!q.empty())
  {
    struct treenode* temp = q.front();
    q.pop();
    cout << temp->data << " ";
    if(temp->left)
    q.push(temp->left);
    if(temp->right)
    q.push(temp->right);
  }
}

//Driver Function
int main()
{
  struct treenode* root2 = NULL;
  struct treenode* root = createNode(1);
  root->left = createNode(3);
  root->right = createNode(2);
  root->right->left = createNode(5);
  root->right->right = createNode(4);
  level_order(&root);
  mirror(root);
  printf("\n");
  level_order(&root);
  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
     1 3 2 5 4

     1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Can you please suggest my logic for binary Tree was correct or not ?? @Anoop Toffy

Comment: Yup logic was right. It was just the way you handled memory references that was not right.

Comment: thanx @Anoop Toffy

Answer (score 0):

```
//Function for creating Binary Tree
//Assuming *root for original tree and *root2 for mirror tree
//are declared globally
void insert(int data)
{
struct treenode* temp;
if(root2 == NULL)
{
root2 = createNode(data);
return;
}
else{
queue<treenode*> q;
q.push(root2);
while(!q.empty())
{
  temp = q.front();
  q.pop();
  if(temp->left)
  q.push(temp->left);
  else{
    temp->left = createNode(data);
    return;
  }
  if(temp->right)
  {
    q.push(temp->right);
  }
  else{
    temp -> right = createNode(data);
    return;
  }
 }
 }
 }
//Iterative version for Mirror of a Binary Tree 
void mirrorBinaryTree()
{
struct treenode *front;
queue<treenode*> q;
q.push(root);
while(!q.empty())
{
  front = q.front();
  insert(front->data);
  q.pop();
  if(front->right)
  q.push(front->right);
  if(front->left)
  q.push(front->left);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier if you code it recursively. Some such as:

```
Node * mirror(Node * root)
{
  if (root == nullptr)
    return nullptr;

  Node * r = new Node; // here we will copy the root
  r->key = root->key; // or whatever the root contains
  r->left = mirror(root->right);
  r->right = mirror(root->left);

  return r;
}
```